# How do I encrypt large files in Python?

Tags: python, performance, security, encryption, rsa

I'm making an antivirus in Python (for fun) and I'm attempting to encrypt a malicious file so that it is unspreadable and inaccessible. I want to encrypt it using a public key-private key system like RSA.

Here's my current code using Flask:

```py
@app.route('/getstatus', methods=['GET'])
def getstatus():
    values = request.get_json()
    id = values['id']
    size = values['size']
    if id in IDS:
        status = IDS[id]['status']
    else:
        pubkey, privkey = rsa.newkeys(size)
        IDS[id] = {'id': id, 'status': 'INFECTED', 'pubkey': pubkey.save_pkcs1("PEM").decode('utf-8'), 'privkey': privkey.save_pkcs1("PEM").decode('utf-8')}
        status = 'INFECTED'
    with open("ids.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump({'ids': IDS}, f)

    return jsonify({'status': status})
```

I keep track of the largest file before sending it over to become the key size (multiplied by 8 to allow for padding)
But my issue is it takes incredibly long to generate the key even for smaller files like images and text. Is there a faster way to encrypt these files with a public key and private key?

TLDR;
I'm making sure nothing can be set on the client side such that the virus can't disable the antivirus. RSA keygen is too slow. Any pubkey/privkey systems that are faster?

Comment: I'm not a security expert, but AFAIK you don't create such large keys. If it must be an individual key for each file, do maybe 2048 or 4096 bits. Otherwise, I would just create a key upfront for this purpose and use this.

Comment: If you're using RSA, key sizes are typically  1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, or in the most extreme circumstances 16k.  The key size is *not* the file size.  And as @OlafDietsche says above, typically usage is that you just pick a key that's independent of what you're encrypting.

Comment: @OlafDietsche yes I know they are independent of each other, but even creating a key of length 4096 results in an error message saying that it's too small

Comment: Asymmetric cryptosystems like RSA are generally not meant to encrypt any big data. They are used to safely exchange keys on an unsafe channel so to then encrypt data (e.g. like big files) using this key and a symmetric cryptosystem. Besides, RSA is known to be slow. The current standard is AES (Rijndael). AES is very secure as long as the key is strong, not shared, on a safe place, and the bloc method used is also strong. AES-256 is so safe it is actually used by the NSA for top-secret information. Note that AES can be computed natively by x86-64 CPUs to reach a quite-high bandwidth.

Comment: Just use a hybrid cryptosystem. Encrypt a random AES "data" key that you used to encrypt the file. Store the encrypted AES key with the file. If you want to use a public key *per file* then you're better off using ECIES but yeah, that's a bigger learning curve. Normally the asymmetric key pair is a static key (as you need to trust the public key).

Comment: You haven't stated what Python library you're using. Just in case it is this one https://github.com/sybrenstuvel/python-rsa, it mentions on its Github page >"Python-RSA is a pure-Python RSA implementation." This might already be a hint, that it is not the fastest around.